# Given $v\in\mathbb R^3$, what are the solutions $A\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ of $A^2=I+vv^{T}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following question arose while deriving the explicit form of symmetric Lorentz transformations:

> Given $v\in\mathbb R^3$, what can we say about the set
> \begin{equation}
> \{A\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}:A^2=I+vv^{T}\}\ 
> \end{equation}
> (with $I\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ being the identity matrix)?

Are there any analogies to the case where $A$ and $v$ are real numbers, i.e. are there exactly two solutions which differ by a minus sign?

Comment: Is "$1$" the identity matrix ? Then, I think, "$I$" or "$I_3$" would be better.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the suggestion, I have edited the question. And yes, you have interpreted the question in the right way.

Comment: Do you want $A$ to be symmetric as well? (that limits somewhat the solution space)

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Thank you for the important remark, yes, $A$ is assumed to be symmetric (for me this followed from the symmetry of the Lorentz transformation, but of course this is not clear for the reader, sorry).

Comment: When $v\ne0$, the case $n<3$ is fundamentally different from the case $n\ge3$, because $A$ can have infinitely many symmetric square roots when it has repeated eigenvalues. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4218548) for instance. Similarly, if $v$ is allowed to be zero,  the case $n=1$ is fundamentally different from the case $n>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer, we don't assume that $A$ is necessarily symmetric.

Suppose that $v\not = 0$ and let $w$ be any vector independent from $v$. Suppose that $A v = w$. We have $A w = A^2 v = (1 + |v|^2) v$,
hence $A^2 w = A(A w) = (1 +|v|^2) A v= (1 +|v|^2) w$, but by hypothesis, $A^2 w = w + (v^T w) v$ hence $|v|^2 w  = (v^T w) v$, a contradiction.

It follows that $v$ and $Av$ **are necessarily colinear**, hence $A v = r v$ for some number $r$, hence $A^2 v = r A v = r^2 v$ but $A^2 v = (1 + |v|^2) v $ hence $r = \pm\sqrt{1 + |v|^2}$ hence
\begin{equation}
A v = \pm \sqrt{1 + |v|^2} v := r v
\end{equation}
Now we have
\begin{equation}
A^3 = A + (Av)v^T = A + r v v^T = A + r (A^2 - I)
\end{equation}
hence $A$ annihilates the polynomial
\begin{equation}
P(x) = x^3 - r x^2 - x + r = (x^2-1)(x - r)
\end{equation}
It follows that besides $r$, the only possible complex eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $-1$, furthermore, any eigenvector not colinear to $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A^2$, hence it must be orthogonal to $v$.

The minimal polynomial cannot be $x-r$ because $A\not = r I$, hence there is at least one non zero eigenvector $w\in v^\perp$ such that $A w = \epsilon w$ with $\epsilon=\pm 1$. Let now $u$ be a vector in $v^\perp$ independent from $w$.

Suppose that $A u = \alpha v + \beta w + \gamma u$, then
\begin{equation}
u = A^2 u = \alpha r v + \beta \epsilon w + \gamma
(\alpha v + \beta w + \gamma u)
\end{equation}
This implies
\begin{equation}
\gamma^2 = 1,\quad\alpha(\gamma+r) = 0,\quad\beta(\gamma +\epsilon)=0
\end{equation}
As $\gamma + r = r \pm 1 \not = 0$, it follows that $\alpha = 0$ which means that **the plane ${\cal P} = v^\perp$ is stable by $A$**.

The restriction $A_P$ of $A$ to ${\cal P}$ satisfies $A_P^2 = I_P$ which means that $A_P$ is either $\pm I_P$ or a (non necessarily orthogonal) symmetry with respect to a line, that is to say it has an eigendirection for the eigenvalue +1 and an eigendirection for the eigenvalue -1.

Such a matrix can be represented as
\begin{equation}
A = \pm\frac{\sqrt{1 + |v|^2}}{|v|^2}v v^T
\pm \frac{w (v\times u)^T}{\det(v, w, u)}
\pm \frac{u (v\times w)^T}{\det(v, w, u)}
\end{equation}
where $w$ and $u$ are independent vectors orthogonal to $v$ but not necessarily mutually orthogonal.

Comment: Could you please explain why $v\times w=AA(v\times w)$?

Comment: I forgot a detail. It turns out that $v$ and $A v $ cannot be independent.

Comment: Are you assuming $A^2=(1+v^Tv)I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: I am asking because this is different from $A^2=I+vv^T$

Comment: Yes but $A^2 v = v + v v^T v$ and $v^T v$ is a number, equal to $|v|^2$, hence $A^2 v = (1 + |v|^2) v$.

Comment: I am currently working my way through your answer. I don't see how you obtain the following result:$$A v = \pm \sqrt{1 + |v|^2} v $$Inserting $A^2=I+vv^T$ in both sides of $AA^2v=A^2Av$ I get$$Av=\frac{v^TAv}{|v|^2}v=\frac{\langle v|A|v\rangle}{\langle v|v\rangle}v$$

Comment: see my edits above.

Answer (score 4):

If $a,b\in\mathbb R^3$ are unit vectors such that $\{ v/\|v\|,a,b \}$ is an orthonormal base of $\mathbb R^3$, then any $A$ of the form $\pm\frac{\sqrt{1+\|v\|^2}}{\|v\|^2}vv^T\pm aa^T\pm bb^T$ will work. Conversely if $A$ is a solution to your equation then it can be written like I described, the reason is that the square root of a positive definite symmetric matrix $U \Sigma U^T$ are $U\begin{bmatrix} \pm\sqrt{\Sigma_{11}}&0&0\\0&\pm\sqrt{\Sigma_{22}}&0\\0&0&\pm\sqrt{\Sigma_{33}} \end{bmatrix} U^T$ and your equation forces one eigen vector of $I+vv^T$ to be $v$, the rest is free (two dimensions of $U$ and the $\pm$ signs).

Comment: I don't think this answer gives all the solutions because matrices having non necessarily orthogonal eigenvectors for $+1$ and $-1$ in the plane orthogonal to $v$ also satisfy $A^2 = I + v v^T$. This answer implies that two such eigenvectors are necessarily orthogonal. It describes only the symmetric solutions.

Comment: Yes it does, but a comment by the OP suggest that it is assumed that $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: I hadn't read this comment, thanks. Yet, it is still interesting to study the problem without this assumption.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thanks, I had the wrong scaling, now it should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

When $v\neq 0$ then go to an o.n.b $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ with say $e_3$ in the direction of $v$. Then $C=I+vv^T$ takes the diagonal form $C={\rm diag}(1,1,\lambda^2)$ with $\lambda>1$. If $f_3=Ae_3$ was linearly independent from $e_3$ then $A f_3=\lambda^2 e_3$ would imply that the kernel of $A^2-\lambda^2$ was two dimensional which is not the case. Thus $Ae_3=\pm \lambda e_3$. $A$ has to preserve the the span of the first two basis vectors $V=\langle e_1,e_2\rangle$ and $A^2$ is the identity on $V$. When $A$ is symmetric this implies that $A$ is the identity, minus the identity (on $V$)
or a reflection. For the latter case you have:
$$ A = \pmatrix{a & b & 0 \\ b & -a &0 \\ 0 & 0 & \pm\lambda}$$
for any $a,b$ with $a^2+b^2=1$ (the eigenvalues are thus $1,-1,\pm\lambda$).

When $v=0$, $A^2=I$. Then $P=(I+A)/2$ and $Q=1-P=(I-A)/2$ are orthogonal projections and $AP=P$, $AQ=-Q$. If either of them has zero rank $A=\pm I$. If $P$ has rank 2 you again have a reflection $A =I-2nn^T$ for some unit vector $n$, and if $Q$ has rank 2, then $A$ is minus a reflection $A=2nn^T -I$. I think this goes through all the possible symmetric solutions.
The non-symmetrical ones yield
a somewhat larger space of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

When v=0 we get $A^2=I$ and hence we get A. When v$\ne$0 then $vv^T$ is a rank one positive semi definite matrix and hence I+$vv^T$ is a positive definite matrix with a unique square root.

Comment: Uniqueness holds only for the positive symmetric square root.

Comment: “A” is not a given matrix. We are solving for A. Only v is a given vector. I +vv^T is symmetric positive definite.